# Height & width of bitmap inside imageView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I use imageView to hold bitmap, e,g current bitmap has 100 x 100 pixels. Using following xml file.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/pimage"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

However with change in imageView xml file, height and width of bitmap changes too.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/colorbar"/>
```

How can i find new height and width of bitmap? I need to use height and width as global parameter which i can use in other function inside same class.

```
final int[] imageWidth = new int[1];
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //get Image Width and height here
        imageWidth[0] = image.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
        //Then remove layoutChange Listener
        ViewTreeObserver vto = image.getViewTreeObserver();
        Log.d("Height12", Integer.toString(imageWidth[0]));
        //phaseimage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
Log.d("Height12", Integer.toString(imageWidth[0]));
```

Inside function it is 728 and outside its 0.

Comment: you need to hook into the event that triggers right after the imageview is ready for displaying

Comment: Have you tried my answer @Sulabh Tiwari

Comment: Just a moment i am testing it now, however i used viewTreeObserver before but problem is that initial value is always 0

Comment: If you use viewtreeObserver after setting bitmap, value wont be 0. I am using same for finding imageview width and height.

Comment: if you mean: `"what is the scale factor used to draw my bitmap"` then see `ImageView#getImageMatrix` method

Comment: `How can i find new height and width of bitmap?` what bitmap are you talking about? the one you use in `ImageView#setImageBitmap` ?

Comment: image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);     image.setImageBitmap(pngimage);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution to my problem.

```
int imageWidth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.phase);
    onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus());
    Log.d("log", Integer.toString(imageWidth))}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    int width=phaseimage.getWidth();
    int height=phaseimage.getHeight();
    imageWidth = width;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting bitmap to imageview, use ViewtreeObserver Like Below :

```
//Your Imageview Reference
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

final ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        //get Image Width and height here 
        int imageWidth = imageView.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = imageView.getHeight();

        //Call anyfunction which uses width and height here
        function(imageWidth,imageHeight);

        //Then remove layoutChange Listener 
        ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else { 
            vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: this will work, i tried this with button before. and you must make sure that your content has set. if you try this in oncreate then you might get some error.. otherwise this answer is working(tried and tested with button)

Comment: In `oncreate()` after setting everything and at the end if you use this it works, because `onGlobalLayout()` is called when viewTree changes.

Comment: i used this method inside onCreate, and it is not able to identify linearlayout in this line ViewTreeObserver vto = linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver();      Moreover i am not able to use imageWidth outside this method.

Comment: I updated the answer. It is not linearlayout, it is imageview. And use global variables instead of local variables where you get width and height.

Comment: I have updated my post, can you have a look at it. Value outside this function is 0. I need to use imageWidth as an input in my other function.

Comment: After the View is displayed on window, the `onglobalLayout()` is called. If you want to send width and height to some functions, call function inside `onGlobalLayout()` method after getting width and height. Global Variable means variables declared outside `onCreate()`